# How to programmatically come to rootViewController without using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using swift in iOS. I have to navigate back to my rootViewController from the current UIViewController by clicking on a button and I am not using UINavigationController.

I have made action on a button in my root rootViewController which triggers the segue and goes from root UIViewController to the next VC by the following code:

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSignUp", sender: nil)`

I can't find any answers to it without the navigation controller.

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://medium.com/@harshalwani/ios-unwind-segue-3e67bf0296f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your button action:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement unwind segue.
In RootController:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromViewController(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

In nextVC in IB, connect the button to exit button at top of VC window in IB and select unwindFromViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you have a segue and you are presenting modally the next `ViewController` you can dismiss it.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But if you are very down in the chain of `viewController` has presented few more and want to return to root then you can do a `unwindSegue`

```
@IBAction func unwindFromViewController(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```